# In CherryPy, is it possible to alias a folder name?

Tags: python, localization, cherrypy, cjk

I'm using CherryPy.  I have a folder named "zh-cn" -- which means that I'm using Mainland China's version of written Chinese - Simplified Chinese.

Here is my code. Notice how I used an underscore? This works.

```
class ChineseFlashcards:
    zh_cn = ChineseFlashcards_zh_cn()
    en = ChineseFlashcards_en()
```

My problem is that I'd rather use a hyphen because I think it's "more correct".  However, you may not use a hyphen like that in Python.  It's not allowed.  This throws an error:

```
class ChineseFlashcards:
    zh-cn = ChineseFlashcards_zh_cn()
    en = ChineseFlashcards_en()
```

What I'm looking for is some kind of CherryPy attribute that will alias the identifier.  Something like this (but this is not legal)

```
class ChineseFlashcards:
    @cherrypy.expose(alias=['zh-cn'])
    zh_cn = ChineseFlashcards_zh_cn()
    en = ChineseFlashcards_en()
```

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1: If you're using CherryPy 3.2 or better, just call it 'zh_cn'. See http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/dispatching.html#special-characters

Solution 2: you can use `setattr` to bind attribute names which are not legal Python identifiers:

```
class ChineseFlashcards:
    en = ChineseFlashcards_en()

setattr(ChineseFlashcards, 'zh-cn', ChineseFlashcards_zh_cn())
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to handle that in your own `index` method.  something like this:

```
class ChineseFlashcards:
    zh_cn = ChineseFlashcards_zh_cn()
    en = ChineseFlashcards_en()

    aliases = {'zh-cn': zh_cn}

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, locale, *args, **kwargs):
        if arg in self.aliases:
            return aliases[locale](*args, **kwargs)
```

`en` will still work as normal, so will `zh_cn`, and any url not recognized will go through `index`, and it will look in it's own dict of aliases.